# How to make HTTP POST request from front-end to Spring?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, rest, http

I'm trying to set up a webapp with ReactJS as the front-end and a Java back-end connected via Spring, but I am new to Spring.

I have two different Requests set up right now in a RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index")
public String index() {
        return "index string!";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/login")
public void login(@RequestParam("user") User user) {
        System.out.println(user);
}
```

I can successfully query /index from the front-end like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3002/index").then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.text());
    return response;
});
```

This prints a Promise that contains the string "index string!"
(I'm not exactly sure how to use this string yet either, but that's not my main problem)

I want to send data using a POST request (should it be PUT?) for a user to log in. My plan is to get a User Object from the request and validate that against my database somewhere else in the Java code. Here is a User object:

```
public class User {
  private String username;
  private String password;

  public User(String uName, String pass) {
    username = uName;
    password = pass;
  }
}
```

and here is the POST request in the front-end:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3002/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          username: username,
          password: password
        }
    });
```

where username and password are strings parsed from HTML.

My understanding is that Spring should create a User Object from the body of the request and let me use that, but instead I'm getting a 400 error without much more detail.

How can I make this 400 error go away and successfully pass data from my front-end to my back-end?

EDIT: here is the top few lines of the returned error

```
VM10542:1 POST http://localhost:3002/login 400 ()
(anonymous) @   VM10542:1
func    @   LoginPage.js:26
```

LoginPage.js:26 is the fetch call.

Comment: What is the body of the 400 response? That might contain more information. Can you debug the request with something like Postman?

Comment: `@RequestParam("user")` - it forces POST URL to be  `'http://localhost:3002/login?user=...`, try to remove that annotation from the method and replace it with `@RequestBody`

Comment: Taking out the @RequestParam("user") makes it a 500 error instead

Comment: Sorry... look at @pawkrol response for details...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, yes POST is the correct method for this type of call.

In your case you have two options:

**Send data as a body**
So that the endpoint implementation will look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/login")
public void login(@RequestBody User user) { 
    System.out.println(user);
}
```

Then send it as a JSON

```
fetch('http://localhost:3002/login', {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: "foo",
    password: "bar"
  })
});
```

**Or send it in params**
So that the endpoint implementation will look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/login")
public void login(@RequestParam("username") String username,
                  @RequestParam("password") String password) { 
    System.out.println(username + " " + password);
}
```

Then send it in params (not the best implementation):

```
fetch('http://localhost:3002/login?username=' + username 
                                 + '&password=' + password, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

Of course you should bear in mind that plain sending a password is not a good idea, but I believe it is for learning purposes. In other case you may take a look at HTTPS.

You may also take a look at other login handling techniques like for starters JWT or maybe you can introduce OAUTH. Good luck!

EDIT:

I haven't noticed that your model class is wrong.
I believe that you need to make it look like this:

```
class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

So the Spring was telling you that the constructor is wrong, because he couldn't find the proper mapping for the `username` and `password` fields.

Comment: note: HTTPS will not help - URL is visible in browser "as is" regardless of protocol

Comment: I tried sending it as a body, but still got a 400 error. I'm seeing a new error in the Java that says
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of logic.User: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?);

Comment: Looks like I need something else in the constructor? Maybe an annotation or something?

Comment: I appreciate the help, but that wasn't the fix. I tried making a dummy constructor (i.e. no params), and that fixed it. Was confused about having to make a public getter for the password; that doesn't seem safe. Anyways, thanks for your help!